# How can I make HTML tags work in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, html

In case of printing the response from another server, which might have too much HTML code, and wants to print in only one single . How can I do it?

```
In jquery we can use
```

`$("#xyz").html("<h1>Hello World</h1><b>thank you</b><strong>good bye</strong>");`

Is there any solution to print it in Angular?

I am trying to print the Hello World in  tag but it shows only text without any effect.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="" ng-controller="personController">
            {{kj}}
        </div>
        <script>
            function personController($scope) {
               $scope.kj=" <h1>Hello World</h1><b>thank you</b><strong>good bye</strong>"
            }
        </script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my output

```
<h1>Hello World</h1><b>thank you</b><strong>good bye</strong>
```

Comment: @dfsq: The problem is that the `kj` variable's content isn't rendering as HTML. That string is literally displayed on the page.

Comment: Read the angular documentation before asking SO questions

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **templates** to build **markup structure**:

```
    <div ng-app="" ng-controller="personController">
        <h1>{{kj}}</h1>
    </div>
```

And **scope variables** to put the **content** into templates:

```
$scope.kj = "Hello World";
```

If you want to build custom tags, use directives.

---

Note, you can also do something like this using `ng-bind-html-unsafe` (or just `ng-bind-html`, depending on the angular version), but it's definitely not recommended in this case:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="personController" ng-bind-html-unsafe="kj"></div>
```

while having:

```
$scope.kj="<h1>Hello World</h1><b>thank you</b><strong>good bye</strong>";
```

This directly answers your question, but it's not really the ideal way to do things in angular.

---

Your updated version:

```
    <div ng-app="" ng-controller="personController">
        <h1>{{kj}}</h1><b>{{ty}}</b><strong>{{gb}}</strong>
    </div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.kj = "Hello World";
$scope.ty = "thank you";
$scope.gb = "good bye";
```

Comment: i am trying to print  <h1>Hello World</h1> <b>thank you</b> <strong> good bye.. </strong>

Comment: Same principle. That shouldn't be in a scope variable, but build a template.